# Is it possible to declare a map at package level in golang?

Tags: go

I want a make global map. I am trying the following

```
package main

import "fmt"

globalMap := make(map[string]string)

func main() {
    globalMap["a"] = "A"
    fmt.Println(globalMap)
}
```

It gives me following compilation error on line `globalMap := make(map[string]string)`:

```
expected declaration, found 'IDENT' mas
non-declaration statement outside function body
```

Looking at the error i understand it won't allow me to create a global map. what could the best way to create a global map ?

Thanks.

Comment: What's with all the downvotes?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can’t use the `:=` syntax outside a function body, but you can use the normal variable declaration syntax:

```
var globalMap = make(map[string]string)
```

Comment: Is there an explanation for why `:=` is restricted to function bodies only? Or why globals must use `var` ?

Comment: @ffledgling it's to simplify parsing, which may make the compiler faster

Comment: My question now is how to do that for (1) multi return-valued functions, (2) `const` with multi-return values functions?